# I downloaded elastic search php vendor folder not found

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I use windows.I downloaded elasticsearch-php https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php but there isn't vendor folder

```
   <?php

    use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;  

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
?>
```

Comment: you need to install it via composer

Comment: @BekirBozkurt, did you check the answer? Please accept if it's correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code example require installing the `elasticsearch-php` library using composer.

Check the [installation guide here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php#installation-via-composer).

If you really don't want to install it using composer - you can try to use [this link](http://website-tech.glerner.com/2013-php-packages-without-composer/) that explains how to use a package without composer.

> Note that elasticsearch requires some other libraries to work, so you might also need to download their source. This is why it's much better to use composer for that.